# Почему при использовании "SWFUpload" переменная исчезает?

Tags: javascript

Я для загрузки файлов на сервер использую [`"SWFUpload"`](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/). Сервер возвращает данные в виде:

> true
>
> Файл успешно загружен.
>
> ID файла

Функция обрабатывает эти данные следующим образом:

```
function uploadSuccess(file, serverData) {

    var response=serverData.split('\n');

    if(response[0]=="false"){
        Boxy.alert(response[1], null, {title: 'Ошибка!'});
    }

    if(response[0]=="true"){
        getUploadEditable(response[2]);

        try {
            UploadedFiles++;
            } catch (ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что после строки `"if(response[0]=="true"){"` переменная `"response[0]"` исчезает. Если `"alert(response[0])"` поставить до этой строки, он отобразит `"true"`, если после - уже ничего не происходит. В чём дело?

Answer (score 1):

> если после - уже ничего не происходит

это говорит о том, что до этой строки не дошло, т.е. где-то либо была ошибка, либо не прошла по условию `if(response[0]=="true")`

Comment: Проанализировал, как мог - ошибок нет. Более того, похожий код используется для загрузки объектов другого формата - там всё нормально, переменная никуда не испаряется.

Comment: >> Проанализировал как мог  

а нельзя воспользоваться `console.log()` или хотя бы `alert()`  и проверить исполняется ли условие и значения хоть всего объекта?!  
А вообще лучше Firebug imho...